# JqGrid Search and Filter in Asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have read lots of sites about handling searching and filtering in JqGrid but i couldn't find solution which make it simple like this :

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetGridData(GridSettings settings)
{
    IQueryable<Room> result = Services.RoomService.GetList();

    var response = Helper.JqGrid.GenerateData(result, settings);

    return Json(response);
}
```

is it possible to have the Helper do the rest(filters, search, multipleSearch, based on types ...) ??
BTW I'm not looking for fluent approach in view and my goal is keep view dynamic and as simple as it can be.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7249036/485474) answer so close to what i need but it has been done for asp.net and he changed some default parameter names in jqgrid definition.

thank you

Comment: So what if he changed default parameters. Change them back

Comment: Lets consider the default parameters of jqgrid setting without any change.What i looking for is exactly what has been done in Telerik Grid.thank you